# Basic string formatting with NIM

Tags: nim-lang

I am trying to do some very basic string formatting and I got immediately stuck.

What is wrong with this code?

```
import strutils
import parseopt2

for kind, key, val in getopt():
    echo "$1 $2 $3" % [kind, key, val]
```

I get `Error: type mismatch: got (TaintedString) but expected 'CmdLineKind = enum'` but I don't understand how shall I fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [`strformat`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strformat.html) Nim-inbuilt library, the same code snippet can be more concise:

```nim
import parseopt # parseopt2 has been deprecated!
import strformat

for kind, key, val in getopt():
    echo fmt"{kind} {key} {val}"
```

---

*Also note that [`parseopt`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parseopt.html) replaces the deprecated `parseopt2` library, at least as of today on Nim 0.19.2.*

Comment: is it possible to have the string in a variable? I'm thinking of a longer string than "{kind} {key} {val}".

Comment: @edmz No, the `fmt` arg needs to be a string literal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ... zah's answer does.

Comment: @edmz Then use `strutils.%` as in OP's code but with the arguments stringified (see zah's answer), or use `strutils.format` which automatically stringifies them.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that Nim's formatting operator `%` expects an array of objects with the same type. Since the first element of the array here has the `CmdLineKind` enum type, the compiler expects the rest of the elements to have the same type. Obviously, what you really want is all of the elements to have the `string` type and you can enforce this by explicitly converting the first paramter to string (with the `$` operator).

```
import strutils
import parseopt2

for kind, key, val in getopt():
  echo "$1 $2 $3" % [$kind, key, val]
```

In case, you are also wondering what is this `TaintedString` type appearing in the error message, this is a special type indicating a non-validated external input to the program. Since non-validated input data poses a security risk, the language supports a special ["taint mode"](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#taint-mode), which helps you keep track of where the inputs may need validation. This mode is inspired by a similar set of features available in the Perl programming language:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/cgi/ch08_04.htm

Comment: Ah, an actual answer to the question, which the accepted "answer" isn't.

Comment: Also, `format("$1 $2 $3", kind, key, val)` auto stringifies the arguments.